# codeigniter adding a new controller gives 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

Every time, when I try to add a new controller in CodeIniter, I get the following:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

*carsadmin.php:*

```
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Carsadmin extends Base_Controller {
       public function index(){
    echo 'Hello World!';
   }
 }
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Do I need to change the routes file?

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['^(en|ar|ru)/pages/(.+)$'] = 'pages/index/$2';
$route['^(en|ar|ru)/profile/([0-9]+)$'] = '/profile/index/$2';
$route['^(en|ar|ru)/admin$'] = 'admin/dashboard';
$route['^(en|ar|ru)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['^(en|ar|ru)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Comment: CI_Controller (if you havn't made your own), now you can access it via  http://example.com/carsadmin

Comment: Try index.php/carsadmin in you url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:-

```
<?php

class Carsadmin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';                   
            die;

    }


}

?>
```

Comment: code igniter log gave me 404 Page Not Found --> carsadmin_controller/index

Comment: @WaleedAkleh You need to access it only as `carsadmin` not `carsadmin_controller/index`

Comment: run only carsadmin/index not include _controller

Comment: i found the solution; somehow adding _controller to Carsadmin_controller class name solved my problem

Comment: not sure but i think you have named your file carsadmin_controller thats why it causing the thing make sure that your class name and controller name should be same (case insensitive)

Comment: it seams that every controller in my project needs to be in this format controllername_controller and the file name format controllername.php i don't know why but this project i was working on witch i took from a previous developer.

Answer (score 1):

YOu will need a htaccess file that has the following written in it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that the controller can be accessed by adding /index in the URL and then the controller name.

Therefore, you need a htaccess file to remove that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use codeigniter v4.2.11
First of all you should create new controller by path
app/Controllers/Carsadmin.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controllers;
    class Carsadmin extends BaseController {
        public function index()
        {
            echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
        }
    }
?>
```

now open file
app/Config/Routes.php
and add new rout

```
$routes->get('carsadmin', 'Carsadmin::index');
```

now open you link in browser

```
http://yousite.com/carsadmin  or  http://yousite.com/carsadmin/index
```